# SSAS All member questions

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2008-r2

Let's say we have a Product dimension with three attributes:

- ProductID (Key)
- Color
- Category

It seems each attribute has an All member.

Each All member is independent? I mean it is technically posible for the All member of Color attribute to have a diferent value than the All member of the Category attribute?

Is is possible to talk about the tuple (All "color", Winter category)?

The product dimension by itself has an All member?

I mean when talking about (2012 Year, Jan Month) when Year and Month belong to the Date dimension (diferent of Product dimension) I should think as if it was refering to:

(2012 Year, Jan Month, ProductID attribute All Member, Color attribute All member, Category attribute All member)

or

(2012 Year, Jan Month, Product dimension All Member)

?

EDIT: Maybe I should rewrite the question... I'm not sure at all how many "all member"'s exist in a given cube and how can I refer to each one of them.

I'm reading a book about SSAS 2008 R2. After some more Reading I think I should update the question, for instance when I'm refering to attributes I should say attribute hierarchies (no user defined).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of answering my question, I would recommend anyone that feels lost trying to understand what the hell is a tuple, or cube spaces, mdx expressions, to read the book "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 MDX Step by Step"